# Angular 4 component reference into another component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a question about Angular 4 in general.

One of my co-workers created a reference of an `AComponent` and bound it as a property to a `BComponent` to access `AComponent`'s properties, instead of binding `AComponent`'s properties individually. Then he also subscribes to an observable in the `AComponent`.

Here is the idea:

```js
// a.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'some-a',
  template: `<some-b [someRefToAComponent]="someRefToThis">...</some-b>`
})
export class AComponent {
  someRefToThis = this;
  someObservable: Observable<any>;
}

// b.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'some-b',
  template: `...`
})
export class BComponent {
  @Input() someRefToAComponent: AComponent;
  someSubscription: Subscription<any>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.someRefToAComponent.someObservable.subscribe(...);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.someSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Here is my question: Is this a bad practice or a very bad practice? And additionally: What could happen in such a case? Could it lead to a memory leak?

Would be interesting to know what happens since I don't have that deep insights into Angular's internal functionality, yet.

Comment: there are definarely nicer ways to achieve such an effect depending on the end goal. On top of my head, it seems quite peculiar why angular did not complain about cyclic dependencies.

Comment: The material datepicker is binded to an input field in a similar way. In that case, the functionality of the input field is tightly coupled to the existence of a datepicker component, so it would be an unnecessary indirection to put a service in between. Take a look here https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/datepicker/datepicker-input.ts#L99

Comment: As always in programming, there is no silver bullet. As long as you think your decisions through and evaluate other approaches in a critical manner, its all good.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo yeah but you can put an optional dependency on the constructor of the parent element...wouldn't that way be a nice way to achieve such an effect

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, I would consider this "against the grain" when it comes to doing things the Angular way. It sounds like what you are really need are Services. Data that needs to interact and be accessible from multiple endpoints, whether they be components, or modules should be contained in a Service.

The other option is to pass data between Components using [Data Binding](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).

This is where understanding the dependency injection system in Angular really becomes a requirement. Services are meant to be Application Singletons that allow components to interact with similar data.

I would really suggest taking a look through the Docs with regards to [Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection).